# Как при выводе на экран игнорировать слова определённой длины?

Tags: c

На вход в программе даётся текст (например "Hello, world! Hi"). Как сделать так, чтобы программа выводила только те слова, в которых кол-во символов больше числа, в значении некой переменной?

Например, в данном случае ("Hello, world! Hi"), при какой-нибудь N = 2,  программа бы выводила только "Hello, world!".

Comment: Нужно входную строку разбить на слова, проверить длину каждого слова и, в зависимости от длины, вывести ее на экран

Comment: Эх.. Не Си++... А то бы я regex присобачил :)

Answer (score 1):

Если исходная введенная строка должна остаться неизменной, то воспользуйтесь стандартными C функциями `strcspn` и `strspn`

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая основана на решение с указанными функциями.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   255

int main( void ) 
{
    const size_t M = 2;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        char s[N];

        printf( "Enter a sentence: (Enter - exit): " );

        if ( fgets( s, N, stdin ) == NULL || s[0] == '\n' ) break;

        s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        printf( "\n" );

        for ( const char *first = s; *first;  )
        {
            const char *delimiter = " \t";

            size_t m = strspn( first, delimiter );

            first += m;

            m = strcspn( first, delimiter );

            if ( M < m ) printf( "%*.*s ", m, m, first );

            first += m;
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Enter a sentence: (Enter - exit): Hello, world! Hi
Hello, world! 
Enter a sentence: (Enter - exit):
```

То есть при первом запросе была введена строка `Hello, world! Hi`, а при втором запросе просто была нажата клавиша `Enter` без ввода данных, чтобы прекратить выполенине цикла.

Вы можете изменить программу так, чтобы значение минимальной длины слова также вводилось пользователем через консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Разбивайте ввод на слова, и выбрасывайте короткие. Воспользуйтесь, например, функцией `strtok` для разбиения на слова. Что-то типа:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char buf[1024], *s;
    int N;
    printf("Введите строку: ");
    fgets(buf,1024,stdin);
    printf("Введите порог: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(s = strtok(buf," \t\n"); s; s = strtok(NULL," \t\n"))
    {
        if (strlen(s) > N) printf("%s ",s);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: а можно ли сделать тоже самое не используя string.h?

Comment: Можно, но тогда нужна своя функция выделения слов из строки, и даже определения длины строки :)

Comment: @Arden, можно, но смысл изобретать велосипед с квадратными колёсами размером с грузовик?