# Игнорирование символов определённой длины в строке (Си)

Tags: c

Добрый день!

Имеется код, который преобразует двоичный код в символы. Необходимо доработать его так, чтобы при выводе программа игнорировала слова, длина которых меньше или равна N. Кто-нибудь может хотя бы намекнуть, как это сделать? Я уже перепробовал всё что мог.

Пример: вводим 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001000 01101001 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100001 // == Hello Hi world!

получаем (при N = 3) Hello world!

запрещено работать с динамической памятью, инклюдить string.h

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define DELIM ' '

int main(void) 
{
    char *ptr, ch[9];
    char in[255];
    char out[255];
    ch[8]='\0';

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int N = 3;

    fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);
        for (ptr=in, i=0, j=0; * ptr; ptr++)
        {
            if  (i == 8) 
            {
                out[j] = (char)strtol(ch, 0, 2);
                if (out[j]==' ') j++; 
                i = 0;
            }
            if (*ptr != DELIM)
                ch[i++] = *ptr;
        }  
    out[j] = '\0';
    if (j>N) printf("%s\n", out):    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы сразу кошке хвост рубили, а не мелкими кусочками... :( У вас есть (уже были вопросы) как выбросить короткие слова, есть как преобразовать бинарную строку в символьную. В преобразовании бинарной строки в символьную замените вывод на запись в другой строковый буфер, потом возьмите код удаления коротких слов. И все!

Comment: @Harry уже так пробовал. Код компилируется, но stdout пустой.

Comment: @Arden, отладчик как раз для таких случаев и предназначен. За вас гонять программу в нём тут никто не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [первое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585958/195342):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char buf[1024], *s;
    int N;
    printf("Введите строку: ");
    fgets(buf,1024,stdin);
    printf("Введите порог: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(s = strtok(buf," \t\n"); s; s = strtok(NULL," \t\n"))
    {
        if (strlen(s) > N) printf("%s ",s);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Вот [второе решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587340/195342):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * in = "01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111";
    for(char * c = in; *c;)
    {
        int value = 0;
        while(*c == '1' || *c == '0')
        {
            value *= 2;
            value += (*c - '0');
            ++c;
        }
        putchar(value);
        while(*c && *c != '0' && *c != '1') ++c;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Вот мы второе решение перегоняем в строку (я все строки беру прошитыми; перепишете для ввода с клавиатуры сами):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char in[255] = "01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001000 "
        "01101001 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100001";
    char out[255];
    int o_idx = 0;
    for(char * c = in; *c;)
    {
        int value = 0;
        while(*c == '1' || *c == '0')
        {
            value *= 2;
            value += (*c - '0');
            ++c;
        }
        out[o_idx++] = value;
        while(*c && *c != '0' && *c != '1') ++c;
    }
    out[o_idx] = 0;
    printf("%s\n",out);
}
```

Мда, первое решение использует строковые функции... Ну ладно, перепишем его. Итак, окончательно:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N = 3;

    char in[255] = "01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001000 "
        "01101001 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100001";
    char out[255];  // Строка для символов
    int o_idx = 0;
    // Преобразование в символы
    for(char * c = in; *c;)
    {
        int value = 0;
        while(*c == '1' || *c == '0')
        {
            value *= 2;
            value += (*c - '0');
            ++c;
        }
        out[o_idx++] = value;
        while(*c && *c != '0' && *c != '1') ++c;
    }
    out[o_idx] = 0;

    // Идем по словам.
    for(char * c = out, *b; *c;)
    {
        while(*c == ' ') c++;       // Игнорируем пробелы
        b = c;                      // Начало слова
        while(*c && *c !=' ') ++c;  // Конец слова
        if (c - b > N)              // Выводим, если достаточно длинное
        {
            for(;b != c; ++b) putchar(*b);
            putchar(' ');
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Теперь достаточно? И что будет следующим кусочком? :)

P.S. Больше за эту задачу не берусь, надо же и вам что-то оставить... :(

Comment: `char out[sizeof(in)+1];` :-)

Comment: @Harry огромное спасибо! Нет слов, чтобы выразить мою вам благодарность!